# Graphics using C language (GCC Compiler)

Tags: c, gcc

I am new to C language, and i am using `Codeblocks` as an IDE and GCC compiler, and i want to write generic codes , which will be same for all the platform and not using any codes specific to windows. For example `clrscr()` is a function to clear the console, which do not work with GCC compiler, or `system("cls")` which is only for windows.I want to do everything what C can do but the code which i will write should be complied in any environment... Similalry for graphics using GCC...I don't know if my question is explanatory..Please advice me..Thank you

Comment: You can't do graphics with pure C or C++. You need to add a graphics *library* (kind of module) to your program. There are many of them out there. I recommend you to use one called `SDL 2`. Just google it.

Comment: so these graphic libraries are platform dependent??

Comment: Some of them are. SDL works basically everywhere - Win, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS and even PSP and other platforms.

Comment: Will surely look at that. Thanks , anyway, just out of curiosity.. I just need to print a single pixel (green color) on my console.. without using any libraries with same GCC. and code should be generic... Is it possible?? or can you show e some way...thank you.

Comment: That's impossible in pure standard C/C++.

Comment: or perhaps i would have to use machine code to do these things...well, i mean, this is how OS are made..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106253/discussion-between-holyblackcat-and-shiva-acharjee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For console work (the text screen) please use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html).  While there are plenty of commands to clear the screen, on Linux systems the screen is not a simple thing; rather it is an emulated single-purpose computer attached to an emulated centralized computer.  The details of this teletype terminal (tty) will make clearing the screen difficult to program because it will need all the commands for all the possible ttys.

Yes, we don't use as many as we did in the past, but `ncurses.h` will prevent you from encountering bugs later (which is when they are always harder to fix).

For graphics, you will need a "windowing system" of which X11 is nearly always used on Linux.  You don't need to install it, but your program will need to interact with it.  This is painful (X11 supports a lot, so there would be a lot of boiler-plate codE) and I recommend that you instead use a "GUI Toolkit" to handle your windowing / widget needs.

If you need 3d graphics, then I'd look into OpenGL and run it within the context of a windowing toolkit.

You will quickly find that the same libraries do not exist on all platforms.  For example, I cannot write basic code to use a Microsoft COM button on Linux and expect it to work.  To make the code multi-platform (a goal you have stated), you need to use (ONLY) one of the approaches:

- Write your code against a platform that makes guarantees it will work the same on all the supported platforms you wish to target.
- Write your code against a library that adapts to the supported platforms you wish to target.
- Write your code against a "multi-platform API" which you then adapt to perform platform-specific operations.

Since you mentioned C as your language of choice, the first option is not available to you.  C does not provide multi-platform support by hiding the platform elements (as Java would).  However, with the second option, Apache's portable runtime (APR) exists, one can do some interesting things with cygwin.  The third option is the hardest to maintain, but often is used because there are seldom solutions that cover every aspect of what you might desire.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is. Say , C comes with some basic procedures which would work on both linux and windows..right? so in this context.. I want to write using only basic c standard libraries..in this way the same code can be used in both windows or on other system...correct me if i am wrong..thank you

Comment: @ShivaAcharjee Yes, C comes with the standard library, and a few other standards (like file, etc) which would work on both linux and windows.  Unfortunately, the parts that are standard only cover a very small set of functionality, and what you wish to do is not standardized across operating systems.  This means at best you use someone's `if / elseif / else` type library that hides the details from you (none are perfect or complete) or you wind up writing copies of the same thing (probably will happen anyway) running the right copy for the right platform.

Comment: So what you suggest??

Comment: I suggest you start by learning a toolkit, and then with some knowledge of what is involved, re-approaching the issue of multi-platform (GTKv3 is good for C, possibly SDL) __OR__ giving up on being involved in the multi-platform part and letting your platform / language take care of that for you (Java).  The first technique will have you learn the issues, the second technique will have you delivering sooner.  It's your call, and I really don't have enough information to make such a decision for you.

Answer (score 2):

So, based on what I understood you want to do graphics with C? First of all, I have to discourage you, because "doing graphics" in C using for example OpenGL or DirectX is really hard for a beginner, so I advice you to learn deeply C/C++ and everything connected like using external libraries, linking, etc...
Then, if you want your graphic programs to be multi-platform I suggest using OpenGL (or, if you find it too hard, an higher level library).
For learning OpenGL there are 2 main resources, [OGLDev](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/) and [Learn OpenGL](http://www.learnopengl.com)

Answering the other part of you question, multi-platforming can be achieved with abstraction, wich means in this context simply doing something like this:

```
void clear() {
    #ifdef WIN32 //Borlands defines _WIN32_ instead, keep it in mind
    //Do Window things
    #elif defined(__linux__)
    //Do Linux things
    #elif defined(macintosh) //Or __APPLE__
    //Do OS X things
    #endif
}
```

Comment: This is exactly why the statement "SDL works basically everywhere" basically is true. There is not "one" SDL library that automagically works on all those different platforms.

Comment: okay..bare with me...just last question.. So using only standard C libraries which is same for almost all the platform..we willl not be able to write codes to  create a single pixel (any color) on the screen which will be same  for both win and linux?? right?

Comment: You have to search for a C function wich does it or else you'll need to search for a native function in WinAPI, libc etc... For all of your platforms